# Setting new pages linked by an Activity

Tags: java, android

In the application I am writing, I have a main class which extends the ListActivity - it contains a list of elements. I want these elements to link to a different page (an xml one, or perhaps a View object). However, I realised one cannot use the method `setContentView(int)` on a ListActivity object.

What's to be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain bit more what exactly you want to do, with some code snippet? Are you trying to launch another activity when some one clicks on an item in the ListView?

Comment: I'm just trying to put up a new page once an item is clicked. For example, writing description of the items. I am afraid I can't post any code because none works :o)

Comment: when you say page you mean new Activity?

Comment: I'm not so sure about the terming, but I think I mean a new View - just a blank screen with some text in it. Hitting the "back" key should bring me back to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to launch a new activity.

You have to override the `onListItemClick` method of `ListActivity`.

Here is the code.

```
// ListView l points to list view whose item user clicked
// View v points to the item in the list view on which the user clicked
// int position is the position index of the item in the list
// long id is the id assigned to the item. This id is assigned using the ListAdapter, CursorAdapter etc.
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // I am using getApplicationContext() as it is more safe then just passing `this`
    Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ActivityToRun.class);

    this.startActivity(i);
}
```

NOTE: You have to improve on this skeleton depending upon your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the right direction. But, what's that `activity` in `activity.startActivity(i)`? I tried to put both `this` and an instance of the other Activity, and both resulted in a crash.

Comment: sorry it was typo....had fixed it now. `ActivityToRun` is the Activity that you will build like you build the first main activity.

Comment: As I said `this` resulted in a crash too. By looking at the log, it appears that the problem is that it was `Unable to find explicit activity class`, even though I have another (working!) activity in the same package.

Comment: can u dump the stack trace here?

Comment: How do I do that? Also, I just got a call, I've got to run - I'll reply only in a few hours... :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: smiling........well you can get it from DDMS perspective of eclipse, under log cat. Paste that with question.

Comment: Hi, please see the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/7mtaH4KR (don't want the question to be too long).

Comment: The soln to that is simple. Whenever you create a new activity. You have to update your `AndroidManifest.xml` (its in the root dir of your project).Open this file and go to `Application` tab (marked below). Near bottom-left you ll see list of activities and and `Add`` button. Press `Add` and select `Activity`. After pressing `OK` you ll see attributes on the right side. For the `name` attribute press `Browse...`. It will show you all the activities. Choose the one you need. Save the file and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the XML page as a `ListView` and give it the ID `@android:id/list`?

Comment: Looks like it works in the sense of not-crashing, however if in the XML I change the background to red and put a text, what I see after selecting an item is the list with red background and no text...